# openlayers 6: measure tool dosen't show up drawn shapes

Tags: openlayers, distance, area, measurements

I am working on a laravel project, where I need to insert a map in the interface of my application.
I am using openlayers V6.3.1 to create the map with its basic tools.
I still have a problem, measure tool didn't work well after I added other tools like download and layerswitcher tools .
the polygon doesn't appear,and the line can't be continued 
here is the javascript code:

```
@extends('layouts.template')
@section('contenu')
    <script type="text/javascript">

      //definition du vecteur: donnée spatiale
        var style = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#319FD3',
          width: 1
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#000'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff',
            width: 3
          })
        })
      });

      var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          url: 'data/benimellal.geojson',
          format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        }),
        style: function(feature, resolution) {
          style.getText().setText(resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('name') : '');
          return style;
        }
      });
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#ffcc33',
      width: 2
    }),
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#ffcc33'
      })
    })
  })
});
      /**
 * Currently drawn feature.
 * @type {import("../src/ol/Feature.js").default}
 */
var sketch;


/**
 * The help tooltip element.
 * @type {HTMLElement}
 */
var helpTooltipElement;


/**
 * Overlay to show the help messages.
 * @type {Overlay}
 */
var helpTooltip;


/**
 * The measure tooltip element.
 * @type {HTMLElement}
 */
var measureTooltipElement;


/**
 * Overlay to show the measurement.
 * @type {Overlay}
 */
var measureTooltip;


/**
 * Message to show when the user is drawing a polygon.
 * @type {string}
 */
var continuePolygonMsg = 'Click to continue drawing the polygon';


/**
 * Message to show when the user is drawing a line.
 * @type {string}
 */
var continueLineMsg = 'Click to continue drawing the line';


/**
 * Handle pointer move.
 * @param {import("../src/ol/MapBrowserEvent").default} evt The event.
 */
var pointerMoveHandler = function(evt) {
  if (evt.dragging) {
    return;
  }
  /** @type {string} */
  var helpMsg = 'Click to start drawing';

  if (sketch) {
    var geom = sketch.getGeometry();
    if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
      helpMsg = continueLineMsg;
    } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
      helpMsg = continuePolygonMsg;
    }
  }

  helpTooltipElement.innerHTML = helpMsg;
  helpTooltip.setPosition(evt.coordinate);

  helpTooltipElement.classList.remove('hidden');
};


// l'échelle

var unitsSelect = document.getElementById('units');
var scaleType = 'scaleline';
var control;
function scaleControl() {
    control = new ol.control.ScaleLine({
      units: unitsSelect.value
    });
    return control;

}

//zoom slider 
var zoomslider = new ol.control.ZoomSlider();

// mini_map
var overviewMapControl = new ol.control.OverviewMap({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ]
});
//mouse  position
var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
  coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
  // be placed within the map.
  className: 'custom-mouse-position',
  target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
  undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
});

//declaration de la map

  var map = new ol.Map({
                    target: 'map',
                    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
    scaleControl(),
    zoomslider,
    overviewMapControl,
    new ol.control.FullScreen(),
    mousePositionControl,
  ]),
                    layers: [
                        new ol.layer.Group({
                            'title': 'Base maps',
                            layers: [
                                new ol.layer.Group({
                                    title: 'Water color with labels',
                                    type: 'base',
                                    combine: true,
                                    visible: false,
                                    layers: [
                                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                                            source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                                                layer: 'watercolor'
                                            })
                                        }),
                                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                                            source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                                                layer: 'terrain-labels'
                                            })
                                        })
                                    ]
                                }),
                                new ol.layer.Tile({
                                    title: 'Water color',
                                    type: 'base',
                                    visible: false,
                                    source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                                        layer: 'watercolor'
                                    })
                                }),
                                new ol.layer.Tile({
                                    title: 'OSM',
                                    type: 'base',
                                    visible: true,
                                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                                })
                            ]
                        }),
                        new ol.layer.Group({
                            // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
                title: 'Overlays',
                // Adding a 'fold' property set to either 'open' or 'close' makes the group layer
                // collapsible
                fold: 'open',
                layers: [
                    // new ol.layer.Image({
                    //     // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
                    //     title: 'Countries',
                    //     source: new ol.source.ImageArcGISRest({
                    //         ratio: 1,
                    //         params: {'LAYERS': 'show:0'},
                    //         url: "https://ons-inspire.esriuk.com/arcgis/rest/services/Administrative_Boundaries/Countries_December_2016_Boundaries/MapServer"
                    //     })
                    // }),
                    new ol.layer.Group({
                        // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
                        title: 'Census',
                        fold: 'open',
                        layers: [
                              new ol.layer.Vector({
                                title: 'benimellal',
                                visible: false,
                                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                                url: 'data/benimellal.geojson',
                                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
                                }),
                                style: function(feature, resolution) {
                                style.getText().setText(resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('name') : '');
                                return style;
                                }
                             }),
                            new ol.layer.Vector({
                                title: 'sous massa',
                                visible: false,
                                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                                url: 'data/sous.geojson',
                                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
                                }),
                                style: function(feature, resolution) {
                                style.getText().setText(resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('name') : '');
                                return style;
                                }
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [-6.862338, 33.918592 ],
            zoom: 5
        })
    });
var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
                tipLabel: 'Légende',
                groupSelectStyle: 'children' 
            });
            map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
            layerSwitcher.showPanel();



//suite de l'échelle
 function onChange() {
  control.setUnits(unitsSelect.value);
}
unitsSelect.addEventListener('change', onChange);

//suite du partie donnée spatiale

var highlightStyleCache = {};

      var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector(),
        map: map,
        style: function(feature, resolution) {
          var text = resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('NAME') : '';
          if (!highlightStyleCache[text]) {
            highlightStyleCache[text] = new ol.style.Style({
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#f00',
                width: 1
              }),
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
              }),
              text: new ol.style.Text({
                font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                text: text,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                  color: '#000'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                  color: '#f00',
                  width: 3
                })
              })
            });
          }
          return highlightStyleCache[text];
        }
      });

      var highlight;
      var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {

        var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
          return feature;
        });

        var info = document.getElementById('info');
        if (feature) {
          info.innerHTML = feature.getId() + ': ' + feature.get('NAME');
        } else {
          info.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        }

        if (feature !== highlight) {
          if (highlight) {
            featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(highlight);
          }
          if (feature) {
            featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(feature);
          }
          highlight = feature;
        }

      };

      map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) {
          return;
        }
        var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
        displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
      });

      map.on('click', function(evt) {
        displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
      });

      //exporting 
      document.getElementById('export-png').addEventListener('click', function() {
  map.once('rendercomplete', function() {
    var mapCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var size = map.getSize();
    mapCanvas.width = size[0];
    mapCanvas.height = size[1];
    var mapContext = mapCanvas.getContext('2d');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.ol-layer canvas'), function(canvas) {
      if (canvas.width > 0) {
        var opacity = canvas.parentNode.style.opacity;
        mapContext.globalAlpha = opacity === '' ? 1 : Number(opacity);
        var transform = canvas.style.transform;
        // Get the transform parameters from the style's transform matrix
        var matrix = transform.match(/^matrix\(([^\(]*)\)$/)[1].split(',').map(Number);
        // Apply the transform to the export map context
        CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.setTransform.apply(mapContext, matrix);
        mapContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
      }
    });
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
      // link download attribuute does not work on MS browsers
      navigator.msSaveBlob(mapCanvas.msToBlob(), 'map.png');
    } else {
      var link = document.getElementById('image-download');
      link.href = mapCanvas.toDataURL();
      link.click();
    }
  });
  map.renderSync();
});
      //suite dessin
   map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) {
          return;
        }
        var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
        displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
      });

      map.on('click', function(evt) {
        displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
      });

map.on('pointermove', pointerMoveHandler);

map.getViewport().addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  helpTooltipElement.classList.add('hidden');
});

var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');

var draw; // global so we can remove it later


/**
 * Format length output.
 * @param {LineString} line The line.
 * @return {string} The formatted length.
 */
var formatLength = function(line) {
  var length = line.getLength();
  var output;
  if (length > 100) {
    output = (Math.round(length / 1000 * 100) / 100) +
        ' ' + 'km';
  } else {
    output = (Math.round(length * 100) / 100) +
        ' ' + 'm';
  }
  return output;
};


/**
 * Format area output.
 * @param {Polygon} polygon The polygon.
 * @return {string} Formatted area.
 */
var formatArea = function(polygon) {
  var area = polygon.getArea();
  var output;
  if (area > 10000) {
    output = (Math.round(area / 1000000 * 100) / 100) +
        ' ' + 'km<sup>2</sup>';
  } else {
    output = (Math.round(area * 100) / 100) +
        ' ' + 'm<sup>2</sup>';
  }
  return output;
};

function addInteraction() {
  var type = (typeSelect.value == 'area' ? 'Polygon' : 'LineString');
  draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: type,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        lineDash: [10, 10],
        width: 2
      }),
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        })
      })
    })
  });
  map.addInteraction(draw);

  createMeasureTooltip();
  createHelpTooltip();

  var listener;
  draw.on('drawstart',
    function(evt) {
      // set sketch
      sketch = evt.feature;

      /** @type {import("../src/ol/coordinate.js").Coordinate|undefined} */
      var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;

      listener = sketch.getGeometry().on('change', function(evt) {
        var geom = evt.target;
        var output;
        if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
          output = formatArea(geom);
          tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
        } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
          output = formatLength(geom);
          tooltipCoord = geom.getLastCoordinate();
        }
        measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
        measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
      });
    });

  draw.on('drawend',
    function() {
      measureTooltipElement.className = 'ol-tooltip ol-tooltip-static';
      measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
      // unset sketch
      sketch = null;
      // unset tooltip so that a new one can be created
      measureTooltipElement = null;
      createMeasureTooltip();
      ol.Observable.unByKey(listener);
    }, this);
      }


/**
 * Creates a new help tooltip
 */
function createHelpTooltip() {
  if (helpTooltipElement) {
    helpTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(helpTooltipElement);
  }
  helpTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  helpTooltipElement.className = 'ol-tooltip hidden';
  helpTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: helpTooltipElement,
    offset: [15, 0],
    positioning: 'center-right'
  });
  map.addOverlay(helpTooltip);
}


/**
 * Creates a new measure tooltip
 */
function createMeasureTooltip() {
  if (measureTooltipElement) {
    measureTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipElement);
  }
  measureTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  measureTooltipElement.className = 'ol-tooltip ol-tooltip-measure';
  measureTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: measureTooltipElement,
    offset: [0, -15],
    positioning: 'bottom-center'
  });
  map.addOverlay(measureTooltip);
}


/**
 * Let user change the geometry type.
 */
typeSelect.onchange = function() {
  map.removeInteraction(draw);
  addInteraction();
};

addInteraction();



    </script>
@endsection
```